# Highcharts Straight-line value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I already have a basic line graph for highcharts. What I wanna do is add just a straight line across (with a constant y = some value) straight through the range of the x's.

Is there a way to do that or do I have to put data points everywhere even if its the same y value everytime?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [plotLine](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines).
This will let you specify a yValue and it just goes straight across regardless of zoom level on xAxis. 
You would add it like this:

```
yAxis: {
  plotLines: [{
    color: 'blue',
    width: 2,
    value: 150,
    dashStyle: 'longdashdot'               
  }]
}
```

Comment: how should i do, if i need to have multiple plot lines in a single axis? Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many as you want. Do something like plotLines: [{plotLine1 params}, {plotLine2 params}, ..., {plotLineN params}].

Answer (score 1):

You can use HighCharts.Renderer.path() to draw a line on the chart. See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path()

Comment: but i wanna draw given a value that still applies to the graph. it's just that it's a single value. i guess i could use the renderer but i have to pinpoint the starting point of the graph if there's no other way

Comment: nvm, i got it now. sorry if my desc was poorly worded